# Passing 2 parameters with JSON to action struts2

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, getjson

What I'm trying to do is to pass something like this (I'm using the struts2-json plugin)

```
var object = {param1 : somevalue, param2 : othervalue};
```

through a `$.getJSON()` call. In my Struts2 action I have this two parameters like the following:

```
public class ActionExample extends ActionSupport {
private Integer param1;
private String param2;
.
.
}
```

with its respectives setters and getters. This two parameters are for a method in which  receives the first param correctly, but the other one always is null and when I sent it from the client side I saw that it has a value. What am I doing wrong?

This is how the call looks like

```
$.getJSON('ajax/getSomething.action', JSON.stringify(object), function(data){
//response manipulation
.
.
});
```

Comment: It's very unclear, at least show show are you calling an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other value for the second parameter should be a string

```
var object = {param1 : somevalue, param2 : ''+othervalue};
```

and use

```
$.getJSON('ajax/getSomething.action', object, function(data){
```

the parameters would be added by `getJSON()`.

Note that your action should be configured properly to handle parameters, i.e. getters/setters, interceptors, etc.